# Doctrine expecting class instead of interface

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, memcached

The project is in ZF2 + doctrine 
We installed the memcached in current working project. Memcached is working fine. First time project loads fine. When you try to load second time it throws an error. Doctrine expects class instead of interface. I am new to doctrine and ZF2 as well.

```
Fatal error: Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException: Class 'WdwTask\Entity\TaskUserInterface' does not exist in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/TMS2/vendor/zendframework/zend-view/src/Helper/Navigation/AbstractHelper.php on line 153
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0040  245376  {main}( )   ../index.php:0
2   1.5424  25728664    Zend\Mvc\Application->run( )    ../index.php:33
3   3.8229  38425752    Zend\Mvc\Application->completeRequest( )    ../Application.php:356
4   3.8229  38425752    Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEvent( ) ../Application.php:384
5   3.8229  38425752    Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners( ) ../EventManager.php:251
6   3.8230  38427560    call_user_func:{/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/TMS2/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php:490} ( ) ../EventManager.php:490
7   3.8230  38427944    Zend\Mvc\View\Http\DefaultRenderingStrategy->render( )  ../EventManager.php:490
8   3.8230  38428480    Zend\View\View->render( )   ../DefaultRenderingStrategy.php:105
9   3.8323  38474200    Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer->render( )   ../View.php:207
10  3.8355  38510640    include( '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/TMS2/vendor/wdw/application/view/layout/layout.phtml' ) ../PhpRenderer.php:502
11  4.1710  41668944    Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer->render( )   ../layout.phtml:29
12  4.1735  41695392    include( '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/TMS2/vendor/wdw/application/view/layout/blocks/sidebar.phtml' ) ../PhpRenderer.php:502
13  4.1864  41952192    Zend\View\Helper\Navigation\AbstractHelper->__toString( )   ../PhpRenderer.php:24
14  4.2209  42131504    trigger_error ( )   ../AbstractHelper.php:153
```

Comment: Please show the code of your `AbstractHelper` class...

Comment: AbstractHelper is a zend-view file. Basically zend-framework file.
I think the problem is memcached is caching all the entites. but i have one interface. Which is not cached and on second reload Doctrine search interface in to memcached. But it's not there. So it's throwing an error.

Comment: Where are you using the `WdwTask\Entity\TaskUserInterface`. An error is caught and thown [here in `AbstractHelper`](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-view/blob/master/src/Helper/Navigation/AbstractHelper.php#L153). Seems like something goes wrong during rendering of your `layout.phtml` or `sidebar.phtml`. You should try to find where exactly it goes wrong.

Comment: I tried to do that and i got another error after commenting those line.

/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/TMS2/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/MappingException.php:96
Message:
Class 'WdwTask\Entity\TaskUserInterface' does not exist
Stack trace:
#0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/TMS2/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/RuntimeReflectionService.php(41): Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException::nonExistingClass('WdwTask\\Entity\\...')

Comment: I tried to install APC today and it gave me the same error. But i got to know that the proxy for interface is not being generated. So any idea about this one.